# for training considering network from last layer in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, generator, conv-neural-network

Here is my model code:

```
Model=Sequential()
input_img = Input(shape=(180,180,3))  # adapt this if using channels_first` image data format


x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='valid')(input_img)

x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='valid',strides=2)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)

y = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='valid')(x)
model=Model(input_img,y)
```

The generator part is given below

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
'\Dipti\medical_image_comp',
    target_size=(180,180),
    batch_size=128,
    class_mode=None)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'D:\Dipti\medical_image_comp\scale0',
    target_size=(180,180),
    batch_size=128,
    class_mode=None)
```

While fitting this simple network through:

```
history=model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    epochs=100,
    steps_per_epoch=training_samples/batch_size,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=testing_samples/batch_size)

    The following error occurs:
```

### Epoch 1/100

```
   ValueError                                Traceback (most recent 
 call last)
 <ipython-input-41-bf2c0dd3bbcf> in <module>()
  4          epochs=100,
  5         validation_data=validation_generator,
```

-     ---> 6         validation_steps=testing_samples/batch_size)

```
  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in 
  wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
    90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' +      signature, stacklevel=2)
```

-       --> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
        92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1254                                         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1255                                         shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1256                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1257 
   1258     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
      ---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

```
  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in 
  fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, 
    callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, 
       max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, 
         initial_epoch)
        2160                                          'a tuple `(x, 
          y, sample_weight)` '
           2161                                          'or `(x, 
          y)`. Found: ' +
        -> 2162                                          
        str(generator_output))
          2163                     # build batch logs
           2164                     batch_logs = {}

        ValueError: Output of generator should be a tuple `(x, y, 
       sample_weight)` or `(x, y)`. Found: [[[[1.         
    0.91372555 1.        ]
  [0.8980393  0.78823537 0.87843144]
  [0.8705883  0.7607844  0.85098046]
   ...
  [0.8313726  0.7411765  0.8117648 ]
      [0.85098046 0.7607844  0.8313726 ]
         [0.83921576 0.7490196  0.8196079 ]]

             [[0.9333334  0.8352942  0.9215687 ]
          [0.8980393  0.8000001  0.8862746 ]
           [0.9294118  0.8313726  0.9176471 ]
              ...
          [0.7803922  0.6901961  0.7607844 ]
          [0.8196079  0.7294118  0.8000001 ]
        [0.8588236  0.7686275  0.83921576]]

        [[0.9176471  0.8235295  0.909804  ]
        [0.854902   0.7607844  0.8470589 ]
        [0.8745099  0.7803922  0.86666673]
        ...
         [0.7686275  0.6784314  0.7490196 ]
        [0.79215693 0.7019608  0.7725491 ]
         [0.83921576 0.7490196  0.8196079 ]]

       ...

          [[0.81568635 0.6784314  0.7725491 ]
          [0.80392164 0.6666667  0.7607844 ]
            [0.8196079  0.68235296 0.77647066]
                ...
          [0.8470589  0.6784314  0.78823537]
          [0.8352942  0.6666667  0.77647066]
            [0.8745099  0.7058824  0.81568635]]

         [[0.7686275  0.6313726  0.7254902 ]
      [0.7607844  0.62352943 0.7176471 ]
           [0.79215693 0.654902   0.7490196 ]
           ...
            [0.8431373  0.6745098  0.7843138 ]
              [0.83921576 0.67058825 0.7803922 ]
            [0.882353   0.7137255  0.8235295 ]]

           [[0.8235295  0.6862745  0.7725491 ]
         [0.7725491  0.63529414 0.72156864]
              [0.78823537 0.6509804  0.74509805]
          ...
      [0.8588236  0.6901961  0.8000001 ]
         [0.86666673 0.69803923 0.8078432 ]
          [0.8862746  0.7176471  0.82745105]]]


        [[[0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
         [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
        [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
                   ...
          [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
              [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
           [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]]

       [[0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
         [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
           [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
         ...
        [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
      [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
       [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]]

       [[0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
           [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
          [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
            ...
         [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
         [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
          [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]]

       ...

           [[0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
           [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
     [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
       ...
           [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
          [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
            [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]]

          [[0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
        [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
            [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
           ...
          [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
              [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
          [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]]

            [[0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
           [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
              [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
            ...
                [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
             [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]
             [0.8705883  0.8705883  0.8705883 ]]]


            [[[0.92549026 0.82745105 0.90196085]
                  [0.89019614 0.7843138  0.8588236 ]
             [0.9176471  0.8078432  0.8941177 ]
           ...
          [0.7960785  0.47450984 0.6627451 ]
        [0.76470596 0.43529415 0.627451  ]
       [0.77647066 0.44705886 0.6392157 ]]

          [[0.9058824  0.8000001  0.8745099 ]
          [0.8941177  0.7803922  0.8588236 ]
           [0.86666673 0.7411765  0.8313726 ]
             ...
                [0.80392164 0.48235297 0.67058825]
         [0.79215693 0.47058827 0.65882355]
           [0.8588236  0.5294118  0.72156864]]

         [[0.83921576 0.7254902  0.80392164]
           [0.87843144 0.75294125 0.8352942 ]
       [0.8235295  0.6901961  0.7843138 ]
     ...
        [0.8078432  0.48627454 0.6745098 ]
          [0.80392164 0.48235297 0.67058825]
        [0.8862746  0.5647059  0.75294125]]

         ...
```

I am not able to get for such a simple network.I have already built lot of models with the same concept,but here this network is not able to trained.Please suggest me the way to train such a simple network with the flow from dsirectory concept using Adam optimizer and MSE as loss function.
I hope you are getting my point

Sir ,through this small network,I just wanted to reduce the size of my images ,After training this network I have to apply the output of this network to a Image Codec and further have to do the reverse process to generate the reconstructed image.Then for testing purpose,I have to compare the original and compared image.Since this is basically a compression task ,reducing the size of images,so particularly my work don't need labels as in the case of classification and regression.I wanted to replicate the results of the paper titled with "An end to end compression framework using Convolutional Neural Networks",And this samll network is basically the first module which I wanted to train using their parameters. You can also check the paper
I hope now you undersatnd the whole problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably in your generator you are returning the labels as the first element of the tuple and the input images as the second element. Swap these two and the problem would be resolved.

Comment: This generator has been taken from keras tutorial only

Comment: I am not getting what to change and swap

Comment: @DiptiMishra Could you please edit your question and include the code of generator? Then I can tell you what might be wrong.

Comment: Edited for generator part

Comment: @DiptiMishra I see. And what is that `fixed_generator`? Post the code for that as well.

Comment: I also dont know that exact usage of this fixed generator,but I had to use this as without this code is giving some errors and after searching a lot i came to this conclusion that I have to use this fixed generator..

Comment: @DiptiMishra Ok, there it is: `yield(batch ,batch)`, the input and output generated are the same and therefore have the same shape. Whereas the output shape of your model is not the same as the input shape. I don't know what you are trying to build, but one way to make the input shape and output shape of the model the same, considering that you are using only `Conv2D` layers, is to remove that `stride=2` argument and also use `padding='same'` for all the convolution layers.

Comment: No ,I dont want to make the input and output shape same.If I am removing this fixed generator then a new error is there.I have editted the code

Comment: @DiptiMishra The model has an output, so you must provide some labels (with the same shape as the output shape of the model) for it to be able to train it. Where are those labels?

Comment: I am not getting,as i am new to keras,,and my work dont need labels,

Comment: @DiptiMishra I can't suggest you anything if I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Please explain the problem you are working on: what is the task (i.e. classification, regression, etc.)? what is the input of the model? what is the output of the model? what is the structure of the data you have? Then I would be able to help you better. Please edit your question to add this information (i.e. don't post it in comments section).